# BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method is not called

Tags: android, android-broadcast, localbroadcastmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an Activity with Fragment inside and IntentService. When I click button dialog fragment opens and I enter my data. After that I click Ok and it calls getActivity().startService(intent). Service calls sendBroadcast(intent) through LocalBroadcastManager, but onReceive() method is not being called. What's wrong? There's my BroadcastReceiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver mApiBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("tag", intent.getAction());
        switch (intent.getAction()) {
            case "register":
                showMessage(intent.getStringExtra(ApiService.EXTRA_ANSWER));
                break;
            case "authorize":
                showProfile((User) intent.getParcelableExtra(ApiService.EXTRA_USER));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

I register receiver here

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();    
    LocalBroadcastManager.
        getInstance(this).
        registerReceiver(mApiBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(ApiService.API_BROADCAST));
}
```

my onDestroy method

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mApiBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

and my method in service which sends broadcast

```
private void sendMessage(Object answer) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(API_BROADCAST);
    if (answer instanceof String) {
        intent.setAction("register");
        Log.d("tag", answer.toString());
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER, answer.toString());

    } else if (answer instanceof User) {
        intent.setAction("authorize");
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_USER, (User) answer);
    }
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call `intent.setAction()`.

You are listening for Intents with action `ApiService.API_BROADCAST`:

- When registering, you use `new IntentFilter(ApiService.API_BROADCAST)`;
- When broadcasting, you use `new Intent(ApiService.API_BROADCAST)`;

That is OK, but if you later call `intent.setAction("register")`, you are overriding the first action you set.

Instead, try passing the sub-action string as an `Extra`:

```
private void sendMessage(Object answer) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(API_BROADCAST);
    if (answer instanceof String) {
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_WHAT, "register");
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER, answer.toString());

    } else if (answer instanceof User) {
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_WHAT, "authorize");
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_USER, (User) answer);
    }
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```